# Twitter API V2 POST Tweet with OAuth 1.0a returns Unsuported authorization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, twitter, oauth

Hi community I've had an error while developing a .NET 7.0 web API to attack Twitter API V2. I'm pointing to this endpoint: [Endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets) and I'm facing a problem that always returns me Unsupported Authentication, Authenticating with Unknown is forbidden for this endpoint. And I have checked that this endpoint works with OAuth 1.0a. So my question is what am I doing wrong? I have followed all guidelines at Twitter API. Even I asked CHAT GPT to pass him the documentation. And it says I'm generating all the signatures well and all OAuth parameters are good. Maybe this helps someone in the community and I hope we can fix it together. I'm using RestSharp for making requests.

I only have one class with two methods (The consumer keys and tokens are valid as I can do it through postman, ill hide them now in code):

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> SendTweet([FromQuery] string accessToken, [FromQuery] string secret, [FromQuery] string message)
    {
        string encodedMessage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);
        string consumerKey = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY";
        string consumerSecret = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET";
        var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var timeStamp = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        string signature = GetSignatureBaseString("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets", timeStamp.ToString(), nonce, consumerKey, accessToken, consumerSecret, secret);
        signature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature);
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets");
        RestClient client = new RestClient(uri);
        RestRequest request = new();
        request.Method = Method.Post;
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumerKey + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp + "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\"" + ",oauth_version=\"1.0\"" + ",oauth_signature=\"" + signature + "\"");
        request.AddJsonBody(new { text = encodedMessage });
        RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        return Ok(response.Content);
    }

private static string GetSignatureBaseString(string url, string timeStamp,
        string nonce, string consumerKey, string accessToken, string consumerSecret, string secret)
    {
        //1.Convert the HTTP Method to uppercase and set the output string equal to this value.
        string Signature_Base_String = "POST";
        Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String.ToUpper();

        //2.Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
        Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + "&";

        //3.Percent encode the URL and append it to the output string.
        string PercentEncodedURL = Uri.EscapeDataString(url);
        Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + PercentEncodedURL;

        //4.Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
        Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + "&";

        //5.append OAuth parameter string to the output string.
        var parameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey},
            { "oauth_token", accessToken },
            {"oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"},
            {"oauth_timestamp", timeStamp},
            {"oauth_nonce", nonce},
            {"oauth_version", "1.0"}
        };

        //6. sort the parameter by key
        var sortedParameters = from p in parameters
                               orderby p.Key ascending
                               select p;

        bool first = true;
        string keyValuePair = "";
        //7. percent encode key and value and append to the output string
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> elt in sortedParameters)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                keyValuePair = Uri.EscapeDataString(elt.Key) + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(elt.Value);
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                keyValuePair += "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(elt.Key) + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(elt.Value);
            }
        }
        Signature_Base_String += Uri.EscapeDataString(keyValuePair);

        string signatureKey = consumerSecret + "&" + secret;
        HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureKey));
        byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Signature_Base_String));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
        return signature;
    }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to the issue? Can you please share the solution?

Comment: No solution found yet :(